# php email safari and chrome

Tags: php, email

So i have the following code in html:

```
<form>
  <input id = "pak" class="w3-check" type="hidden" checked name="Package">
    <label class="w3-validate changeLabel"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="sendBtn w3-button w3-theme">Send</button>
  </form>
```

In php I have:

```
<?php 
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$package = $_GET['Package'];
$message = "Message";

mail($to,$package,$message);
?>
```

And in javascript:

```
$(".pricesBtn").click(function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        var text = $(this).text();
        $("#pak").html(text + " package");
        $("#pak").val(text + " package");
        $("#pak").hide();
        $(".changeLabel").html(text + " package");
```

});

Now when I send the email with chrome, it works as I want, with the Package as titel, but with safari for mac the package title doesn't come trough and with safari for iPhone it does(kind a weird right?).

K.R Tom

Comment: `<input id = "pak" class="w3-check" type="hidden" checked` <<< that's invalid. Hidden inputs don't use `checked`; last I knew; radios/checkboxes do.

Comment: Your hidden input also needs a value

Comment: you also have no element bearing the `pricesBtn` class in your HTML.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for noticing, I changed it but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is another question than the question that you suggested, because in my case the mail function works fine in all browser I have tested, but not in safari for mac. But with safari for iPhone it does work.